# Misleading syntax/parser error: Expected > instead of * in reinterpret_cast

Tags: c++

I am getting a weird syntax error when trying to reinterpret-cast a pointer:

```
void my_function(std::unique_ptr<float[]> ptr) {
    // Some stuff
    ... = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t[]*>(ptr.release());
    // Some other stuff
}
```

I'm getting the following error message:

```
error: expected '>'
      reinterpret_cast<uint8_t[] *>(ptr.release()));
                                ^
```

I have a '<' and a matching '>', so I don't understand what's causing the error. What could be the problem here?

Comment: `uint8_t[]*` makes no sense.  You can't define a pointer to an array like that.  `ptr.release()` returns a simple `float*`, you can cast that to a `uint8_t*` instead, but not to a `uint8_t[]*`. But why are you calling `release()` at all? You are relinquishing ownership of the `float*` pointer, you will have to cast back to `float*` and call `delete[]` to free memory properly before `my_function` exits, or it will leak.

Comment: What is the type `uint8_t[]*`, exactly?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Why answer here?

Comment: This smells of all kinds of wrong. It might be a good idea to fully explain what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really want a *pointer to an array of uint8_t*, as opposed to just a pointer to uint8_t ?

If so, it is written `uint8_t(*)[]`.

But I think what you actually want is most likely a pointer to uint8_t, i.e. `uint8_t *`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're either trying to serialize data, you should be casting to a regular `uint8_t` pointer. For this, just do:

```
reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(ptr.release());
```

Note that `ptr.release()` releases onwership of the pointer owned by the `unique_ptr`, and that deleting a pointer to an array of `float` as a pointer to an array of `uint8_t` is undefined behavior. **Always delete a pointer as it's original type, without casting it.**

I would recommend using `ptr.get()` instead, as this doesn't transfer ownership:

```
reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(ptr.get());
```

**Why you got the error:** The syntax for a pointer to an array is `uint8_t(*)[]`. It's... weird, and until another commenter pointed it out, I didn't know that it existed (it's an artifact of backwards compatibility with C).

Because of that, the compiler doesn't expect to see a `*` after `uint8_t[]`, so it says that it expected the closing bracket of the `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: "pointer to array of uint8_t" is actually a real type in C++, and is spelled `uint8_t(*)[]`.

Of course, the rest of what you said is true (that what OP wants is really a pointer to uint8_t, not a pointer to array of uint8_t).

Comment: Thank you! I fixed my answer!

Comment: You don't know if `get()` should be used instead or not. The OP could very well need `release()`. In which case, the original data should be copied into a new `unique_ptr<uint8_t[]>` and the original deleted.

Comment: @J. Antonio Perez By the way, this would be a pointer to an array of unknown bound, which is, as far as I know (though I could be wrong) not useful for anything.

But it *is* possible to pass around a pointer to an array of *known* bound. This program, for example, will print `1.23`: https://pastebin.com/f2CxBkvQ

Comment: @BrennanVincent There are no arrays involved here. Just pointers to allocated memory.

Comment: @NikosC. can you elaborate?

Comment: Calling `release` and then immediately casting it to a pointer of a different type is a red flag for me, because that seems to imply that the pointer will get deleted as a `uint8_t*`, instead of a `float*`

Comment: @BrennanVincent The `std::unique_ptr<float[]>` parameter of the function is not a pointer to an array. It's just a pointer to something allocated with `new float[some_size]`. It's just a way to have `delete[]` called automatically on it. There's no array (or "array bounds") anywhere.

Comment: @NikosC. I understand that. I'm just saying that "pointer to array of uint8_t of unspecified size" is a real type in c++, regardless of whether it's useful in this example.

Comment: See for example: [this link](https://cdecl.org/?q=float+%28*foo%29%5B%5D)